# how to load data from tables to a dimension using ssis

Tags: ssis, etl

I want to load data from tables to dimension I don't know what to use (controls)
am a beginner all that I need is just a video tutorials that can be helpful for this situation .

this seems hard for me because the dimensions are related to too many tables and loading data from natural table to dimension table require transformation for the data I also want to know how to transform data ...

I'm using adventureworks and adventureworksDW data sources 
and I want to load data to any Dimensiontable in adventureworksDW 
thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [The Data Warehouse ETL Toolkit](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_data_warehouse_ETL_toolkit.html?id=ypKiIM4fZGIC) by Ralph Kimball and Joe Caserta.  Since you are specifically looking into loading dimensions, [etltools.org](http://www.etltools.org/loading/dimensions.html) does a decent job explaining different dimensions and how to load them.  This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141122.aspx) site breaks down the Data Flow Task and each transformation with in the Data Flow Task.  The Data Flow Task provides the easiest way to move data from Source A -> transform it along the way -> to Destination B.  In no way am I saying that it is the only way, nor am I saying it is the most efficient way to load data into a dimension, but it is VERY simple.